# Enable PInch zoom on just img elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, pinchzoom

I have a problem with getting images to zoom on ipad (especially in chrome). I've found tons of solutions online but nothing is working for me. I've change the meta tags for the viewport to be "user-scalable" but it doesn't work for chrome just safari. I know it can be done because I've seen it done on MM Lafleur's site(link below).

Preferably I would like it so the images just zoom in place instead of the whole website, but i'll accept any solution at this point. Any suggestions??

https://mmlafleur.com/shop/rebecca-black

Answer (score 0):

Add this css and you're done...

```
.product-detail-main-container:hover {
    background-size: auto 170% !important;
}

.product-detail-main-container {
    transition: 0.2s all;
    background-size: auto 100% !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.product-detail-main-container .product-detail-zoom-area {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```